# How to split a string to List<string> without splitting words?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Let's say we have a long string we wish to split into strings 64 chars long without splitting individual words:

```
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
```

If we split as such:

```
string.SplitByLength(64).ToList();
```

We'll end up with two strings:

```
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. I
f your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
```

What is the most elegant way of splitting this string so that the first string ends before the `If` and the seconds string begins with `If`?

In other words, how to split a long string into a list of strings equal to or shorter than the desired length while not splitting any of the individual words but rather splitting at the last possible empty space in between words?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815021/split-large-text-string-into-variable-length-strings-without-breaking-words-and-k

Comment: Brad is right. Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752091/re-formatting-free-text-to-fixed-format-text-c/

Comment: Checked both questions and I don't think this is a duplicate. The first question includes the variable line length and the second question multi paragraph splitting...

Comment: I guess we can also state this problem as: How do I elegantly implement word-wrap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give it a max value like 64, and then use that as a index to search backwards and find the first space and split it there. Repeat on the remaining string using recursion and you're done.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SmartSplit(this string input, int maxLength)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i + maxLength < input.Length)
    {
        int index = input.LastIndexOf(' ', i + maxLength);
             if(index<=0) //if word length > maxLength.
            {
                index=maxLength;
            }
        yield return input.Substring(i, index - i);

        i = index + 1;
    }

    yield return input.Substring(i);
}
```

Comment: Added a code sample. Haven't tried compiling it, but the idea is there.

Comment: For the record, [it does work](http://www.ideone.com/jLNf4), but flawed in regards to passing "results" undeclared or just being a memory-hog overall. ;-)

Comment: This is slow because you always cut a single line and create a clone (deep copy) of the rest. Also if there is a single word longer than maxLenght, it fails.

Comment: Like I said, the idea is there. Obviously you could optimize it by passing the original string each time, along with the current index point. It's a simple implementation detail to fix if you find the method becoming a hotspot on a performance profile.

Comment: OK, revised to remove the recursion.

Comment: Both solutions get the job done but the extension methods is more elegant... unless someone comes up with something even better I'll mark this as the answer tomorrow... Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
    var phrase = "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.";
    var regex = new Regex(@"(.{1,64})(?:\s|$)");
    var results = regex.Matches(phrase)
                               .Cast<Match>()
                               .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                               .ToList();
```

EDIT: I got it...

Comment: Not very savy with regular expressions... would this regex split at the period character? If so, what if there was a period after the third word or no period at all?

Comment: oups it's not correct at all you're right, I'll try to make it right

Comment: the . caracter means 'all caracters' the \s means whitespace, the parenthesis means we want to include that in the results

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether it is the most elegant, but why don't you split string on spaces and then have one integer as counter and if it is below 64 you add word and space to stringbuilder, and if it is above 64 then you add current stringbuilder to list, create new stringbuilder and reset counter?

Comment: This would be quite slow and memory intensive, because you create very many objects you actually don't need.